# exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at

Tags: arrays

I have problem when the massage box tell that

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at Pla3d_2.Tkmat<Pla3d_2.java:509>
at Pla3d_2.Tkmat<Pla3d_2.java:327>
```

below are the line of the code for reference

for line 327

```
 /***Construction and overall stiffness matrix of  B Mato (line 326)
 Tkmat(xyz,e1,p1,aj,psaig,aji,detjg,detjgg,gbg1,bmat,dep);(327)
 /***Introduction of boundary conditions (328)
  Fix(nb,n,nband,ix,iy,iz,u,v,w,ib,dtf,ux,uy,uz); (329)
 /***Solutions for system of linear equations (330)
```

and

for line 509

```
 static void Tkmat(double xyz[][],double e1[],double p1[],
        double aj[][][],double psaig[][][],double aji[][][],double detjg[],
        double detjgg[][],double gbg1[][][],double bmat[][],double dep[][]){
        int l,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,ie,je,it,jt,iit,jjt;
        double aj11,aj12,aj13,aj21,aj22,aj23,aj31,aj32,aj33,detj,sum;
        double gek1[][] = new double[6][nodel*3];
        double gek2[][] = new double[nodel*3][nodel*3];
        double gekg[][][] = new double[8][nodel*3][nodel*3];
        double gek[][] = new double[nodel*3][nodel*3];
//
     for(l=0;l<ne;l++){
       for(l1=0;l1<nodel;l1++){
        lc[3*l1][l]  =3*loc[l1][l]-2;
        lc[3*l1+1][l]=3*loc[l1][l]-1;
        lc[3*l1+2][l]=3*loc[l1][l];
       }
       for(l1=0;l1<nodel;l1++){
         xyz[l1][0]=xx[loc[l1][l]-1]; [line 509]
         xyz[l1][1]=yy[loc[l1][l]-1];
         xyz[l1][2]=zz[loc[l1][l]-1];
       }
       for(l2=0;l2<8;l2++){
         for(l1=0;l1<3;l1++){
           for(l3=0;l3<3;l3++){
             aj[l2][l1][l3]=0.0;
             for(l4=0;l4<nodel;l4++){
               aj[l2][l1][l3]=aj[l2][l1][l3]+psaig[l2][l1][l4]*xyz[l4][l3];
             }
           }
         }
       }
```

Can anybody help me...Thank you in advance..:-)

Comment: Exception says at line no 501 you are trying to access the element at -1 index in array which obviously you can't access that's the reason. Now you only can debug the code and check how at this line you are trying to access index -1 try printing the value of l and l1 you will find how it becomes -1.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that your code is pretty ugly and nobody can understand what's going on, check

```
at Pla3d_2.Tkmat<Pla3d_2.java:509>
```

in your stack trace. It's telling you that you are trying to set an object into an Array at line 509 but that Array has grown out of size - there's no more space in that array.